# Firebase Cloud Function not Publishing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to write a cloud function which gets executed every time a sensor reading in the collection "sensor-readings" gets created:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


      exports.createNotification = functions.firestore
          .document('sensor-readings/{sensorId}')
          .onCreate((snap, context) => {

            const payload = {
              notification: {
                title: 'New news',
                body: "Body Test"
                }
            };

            // perform desired operations ...
          return  admin.messaging().sendToTopic("topic",payload);
          });
```

The cloud function gets executed everytime a sensor reading is created but when I try to use
`gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --auto-ack MySub`
to test the outcome of the function, there is no message being published to the topic.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Unrelated point: `functions.config().firebase` is deprecated. Use `admin.initializeApp();` instead.

Comment: @samthecodingman would you mind pointing to the docs showing the deprecation you mentioned?  What's the new practice for importing your config?

Comment: It was removed with the move to V1.0 as [mentioned here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#functionsconfigfirebase_removed). The value `firebase` is also deleted from the `functions.config()` object [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/master/src/config.ts#L84-L106) so it resolves as undefined and so that new code that calls `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` correctly calls `admin.initializeApp();` which will pull all it needs from the environment variables automatically.

Comment: As mentioned in [that link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#functionsconfigfirebase_removed), if you need the configuration object, outside of initialisation/if you need to modify it, you can use `let firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working with a product called Firebase Cloud Messaging, which is meant for sending message to web and mobile applications:

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic("topic",payload);
```

But your command line is working with Google Cloud Pubsub, which is a completely different product:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --auto-ack MySub
```

You can't use FCM to send messages to a pubsub topic.  Again, they are completely different.  And you can't use gcloud to see what's happening with FCM messages.  You would need to do that in your web or mobile app.

If you want to send a messages to a pubsub topic, you should use the [Google Cloud SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub) for that, not the Firebase Admin SDK.